# ASP.NET XHTML Strict Validation & autocomplete=off

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete, xhtml-1.0-strict

We have an ASP.NET form with the following doctype:-

We need to add autocomplete=off (by setting the TextBox property of AutoCompleteType="Disabled") to the input fields but still need the form to pass XHTML Validation (yes I know it's not XHTML valid because of this).

Is there anythign we can do to ignore the autocomplete=off??

Something like:-

!ATTLIST input autocomplete CDATA #IMPLIED

Thanks in advance.

Al.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the autocomplete attribute on the client-side through JavaScript code. I don't think you can define that the attribute should be recognized because you don't have permission to add to the schema that defines XHTML.